# Problem with BOINC on 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, lts

I run distributed computer on a platform called BOINC. Boinc manager connects to the boinc client to manage and view client functions. Everything has been running fine until I restarted the boinc client with the command "sudo service restart boinc-client." After the client restarted Boinc manager is shown as "disconnected" and will not reconnect even after a reboot.
Both the boinc client and manager were installed from the repository.

Comment: Since I'm getting no suggestions should this be reported as a bug?

Answer (score 1):

After much searching I was able to find a solution for my problem so I'm passing it along to someone else who might need it.
Open a terminal and enter the highlighted commands.
 Just replace "username" with you actual user name.(no quotes)

Join the root group:  **sudo adduser username root**
Join the BOINC group: **sudo adduser username boinc**

Allow group to read, write and execute in /etc/boinc-client folder:      **sudo chmod -R g+rwx /etc/boinc-client**
Allow group to read, write and execute in /var/lib/boinc-client:        **sudo chmod -R g+rwx /var/lib/boinc-client**

**Reboot**

Hope this can help someone

Comment: Tank you  I use 
sudo adduser username boinc
sudo chmod -R g+rwx /etc/boinc-client 
sudo chmod -R g+rwx /var/lib/boinc-client